# Ruby on Rails on Azure - does not support package.json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure

Does anyone know when Ruby on Rails on Azure will support package.json files? Currently, the deploy.sh misinterprets rails apps with package.json files as node.js apps. Even without it, Azure has trouble supporting rails even with my (ruby, rails, bundler) versions downgraded and Kudu specific variables set in the app settings. However, the logs / deployment on cli indicate success, even though the deployment is unsuccessful.  Tks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing the ideas. Packages.json is used for .net projects. The equivalent for ruby is a gem file:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-ruby#run-the-application-locally

Comment: I have actually used npm  before with ruby in addition to the gem file, but the issue here was the ruby versions and also the wdm gem. Updated both and resolved the issue.

Comment: Also, in order to use webpacker and the react gems a package.json file is required. Azure needs to fix the node issues.

Comment: my bad. I thought you were trying to use it to restore packages

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by specifying an older node version in app config setting:

[
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
    "value": "8.12.0",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
]

Comment: Can you provide a bit more explanation on how to implement this fix? I added your line directly into the `application.rb` file; and it didn't work. I think that I am not doing something right. Thank you, Karen!